# Network file copy in .NET

Tags: c#, networking, copy, share, sharing

I have an Ubuntu box running a Samba share open to everyone. I can access it via \ip address so I know I have full access to it.

From within my application I am trying the following but it will not work via the ip address only the DNS name.

```
// val = ip address
File.Copy("\\\\" + val + "\\share\\vSphere\\vSphere.exe", Temp + "vSphere.exe", true);
```

I need to use the IP Address as people who are VPN'ing in won't be able to have the program access the dns name only the ip address.

Comment: Where is `val` coming from? Can you check to see if it's an IP address before this code executes?

Comment: In fact, I would assign the expressions in those parameters to local variables, stop in the debugger and see what they're set to.

Comment: Is there an exception being thrown? If so, are there any details in it?

Comment: Using the IP I get The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Using DNS it works just fine.

val is taken from the registry which is set by the installer and is correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, try by giving IP address as below

```
File.Copy(@"\\192.100.1.23\share\vSphere\vSphere.exe", Path.combine(Temp ,"vSphere.exe"), true);
```

if error exist try using impersonate, give user name and password

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);

WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();

File.Copy(@"\\192.100.1.23\share\vSphere\vSphere.exe", Path.combine(Temp ,"vSphere.exe"), true);

context.Undo();
```