# Save/Copy a file in a directory from another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

using : asp .net mvc 4.0, c# , vs10

**strFilePath** holds a path of a existing file in a directory. I want to **save/copy** the **file** into my application's **uploads** directory.

how could i do this. I am trying something foolish, and searching the internet and feeling helpless.

```
string filePath = "foo.txt";
//var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), filePath);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, "~/Uploads");
}
```

Comment: Is the copy operation taking place on the same machine or to a network share ?

Comment: please change `filePath = x.AttemptedValue.ToString();` to constant (like `filePath="foo.ext;"`) so it is clear what you expect there.

Answer (score 3):

`~` symbol is not recognized by [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

Convert virtual path to physical path first and then do the copy.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"));
```

Also, You need permission to the folder where you are copying. You may need to [Impersonate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811222/649524) if the above does not work.

Comment: Is there a way in which we can achieve this without using impersonation ?