# File.Copy from local to shared folder in server

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having problems when copying a .txt from a local server ("D:\AuditFiles") to a shared folder in another server ("\\PrintServer\SharedFolder"). It throws the exception:

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I thought it could be something with the path format, so I tried by adding to the server path an @:

`@Configuration.Manager["Path"]` | `@"\\ServerPath\SharedFolder"`

I've also tried with this format: \\ServerPath\SharedFolder... None of them worked.

By the way its not an access problem, cause i've tried to do the same thing running a command prompt from within c#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C COPY PATH1, PATH2"); //This worked and copied the file.
```

I'd be greatful if someone could give me a clue of what could be the problem here. At least an advice of what to do.

Thanks in advance and sorry me bad english!

Edit:

This is the part of the code that should work:

```
string pathPrevDay = "D:\AuditFiles\enc_" + svr.Name + "_counts" + day.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";

if(File.Exists(pathPrevDay))
{
    File.Copy(pathPrevDay, @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER_PATH"]);
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811017/network-file-copy-in-net

Comment: Do you think your code is irrelevant and therefore not posted it?

Comment: YOu posted the code that works, but not the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Print pathPrevDay and the AppSettings string to console, what do they look like? I'm assuming it's the latter that is wrong.

Comment: Your backslashes in `pathPrevDay` might be causing the problem. Escape them or use a verbatim string by prefixing with `@`. Also, the `@ConfigurationManager` part doesn't make any sense. `ConfigurationManager` isn't a reserved word in C# (at least that I know of).

Comment: Change this `"D:\A` to this `@"D:\A` - the `@` escapes the slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes **and indicate the name of the file** in File.Copy(pathPrevDay, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER_PATH"]);.

Change this:

```
string pathPrevDay = "D:\AuditFiles\enc_" + svr.Name + "_counts" + day.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";
```

to this:

```
string pathPrevDay = "D:\\AuditFiles\\enc_" + svr.Name + "_counts" + day.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";
```

You can also use single slashes (/) instead like this:

```
string pathPrevDay = "D:/AuditFiles/enc_" + svr.Name + "_counts" + day.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";
```

Comment: It didn't worked :( I placed the @ and threw the same exception

Comment: Check out all the paths to guarantee that they exist.

Comment: what "didn't work" - put some detail about what didn't actually work... did it error? does the file actually exist?

Comment: Also, no need for @ in the following code: @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER_PATH"]

Comment: I added the @ to "pathPrevDay" and threw the same exception: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Show me the content of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER_PATH"]. In the configuration file it should be \\ServerPath\SharedFolder (no @ sign). An verify that the path is correct.

Comment: The content of MAIL_SERVER_PATH: <add key="MAIL_SERVER_PATH" value="\\ServerPath\SharedFolder\"/>

Comment: Change your code to this, just for testing: File.Copy(pathPrevDay, @"\\ServerPath\SharedFolder\");

Comment: OH! I see, you need to also indicate the name of the file, not only the path!

Comment: LOL. You're right. Thanks, i selected your answer as the correct one